# Codeigniter : mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
$this->load->config('email');
$this->load->library('email');
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf8';
$config['newline'] = '\r\n';
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from($this->config->item('team'), $this->config->item('team'));
$this->email->to('kashyap.waytoweb@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject(SITE_NAME." - Welcome New User");
$this->email->message('<html><head><title>Hey</title></head><body><h1 style="text-align:center">Welcome To Dash</h1></body></html>');
$this->email->send();
```

This gives me error for additional errors

```
Message: mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header
```

i hae tried converting this but didnt get success. please guide where is the breach. if i remove mailtype  it works but when there is a html it didnt working

i have used simple mail function do this

Comment: This doesn't seem to be using PHPMailer. You need to show an example of the generated message headers so we can see where the problem is - there is not enough information here to work with. I'd also suggest reporting this to CodeIgniter's bug tracker (but search first!).